# How can I make a class that checks if it is being instantiated inside a specific class's signature?

Tags: python, class, oop

I need to make a class where it can check the scope where it is being instantiated. it can only be instantiated inside a specific class's signature

```
class Fish:
    pass

class Water:
    def __init__(self, animal):
        pass

habitat = Water(Fish()) # this should work

class Land:
    def __init__(self, animal):
        pass

habitat = Land(Fish()) # this should not be allowed
fish = Fish() # this also cannot be allowed
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your wording. But the first not-allowed example suggest that you would check if `animal` is of a certain type (or a (sub)class of something), and otherwise perhaps raise a ValueError or TypeError.

Comment: Why is `fish = Fish()` not allowed?

Comment: If you want a Fish to be only created inside a Water instance, then you should create a Fish *inside* the initializer of Water. Because `fish = Fish(); Water(fish)` is practically the same as `Water(Fish())`, and trying not to allow the first version but allowing the second would confuse anyone reading and using your code, and goes against the grain of the language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure the a `Fish` is only allowed with `Water` around, then I would invert the relation, pass a `Water` instance to the `Fish` constructor, and verify inside the constructor that this is indeed a `Water` instance. I.e.,

```
class Water:
    pass

class Fish:
    def __init__(self, habitat):
        if not isinstance(habitat, Water):
            raise ValueError("incorrect habitat for fish")
        self.habitat = habitat

animal = Fish(Water()) # this works

class Land:
    pass

#animal = Fish(Land()) # raises ValueError: incorrect habitat for fish
#fish = Fish() # raise TypeError: Fish.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'habitat'

class Lake(Water):
    pass

freshwater_fish = Fish(Lake())  # also works
```

This way, a fish has a habitat. Which seems more logical to me anyway,
since the other way around, a habitat would have a (single) fish, instead of having a multitude of animals and animal (and plant) species.